# testing "presentingViewController is UIViewController" works fine in one case, fails in other

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Following Apple's documentation for adding and editing information [Apple guide here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementEditAndDeleteBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH9-SW1) I have a Viewcontroller with a tableview. The tableview contains a header with a "Add new" Button. If a table row is selected the detailViewController is pushed onto the stack. The detailViewController is also embedded in a UINavigationController, as in Apple's docs. If "Add new" is pressed, another segue is performed which presents the UINavigationController modally, which in turns shows the detailViewController. This works fine and the animation clearly shows a modally presented ViewController.

The detailViewController contains a Cancel Button in the NavigationBar. If it is pressed the following code is run:

```
@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    var isPresentingInAddActionMode = false
    if let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController{
     isPresentingInAddActionMode = presentingVC is UINavigationController

    }
    streekgidsModel.undoManager.endUndoGrouping()
    print("undo grouping ended and undone")
    streekgidsModel.undoManager.undo()
    if isPresentingInAddActionMode {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
        owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    else {
        fatalError("The MealViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
    }
}
```

The first if-statement checks if the property presentingViewController is present, and if so if it is of type UINavigationController. If so, the viewController is presented modally and should be dismissed. If not it is pushed onto the stack and the owningNavigationController should pop the detailViewController.
Running this code does not work as described by Apple. The check on the presentingViewController shows it is present, but the type check gives back "invalid". This is treated as false. The test on the owningNavigationController succeeds (I think it should fail) and the popViewController is executed. As there was no push, the view controller is not popped or dismissed and is still visible. A second press on Cancel executes the func cancel again, which results in an error as there is no longer a group started in the undo manager.

Baffling thing is that I have the same code in another viewcontroller, with similar UIViewTable and navigation and it works fine.

So to frame the question: why does this not work the way Apple describes it, why does my other view controller work as it is supposed to? Any input is appreciated.

BTW, the fatal error text is straight from the docs so the naming is not relevant and it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking who is presenter.

According to Apple docs on this:

> When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or implicitly) using the present(_:animated:completion:) method, the view controller that was presented has this property set to the view controller that presented it. If the view controller was not presented modally, but one of its ancestors was, this property contains the view controller that presented the ancestor. If neither the current view controller or any of its ancestors were presented modally, the value in this property is nil.

If the docs are correct then your presenter should be your "Viewcontroller with a tableview" which, I guess, is not UINavigationController. If that is the case then you should understand why your code fails.

It depends on your context of course, but I would just simplify a check this way:

```
var isPresentingInAddActionMode = self.presentingViewController != nil 
... // your other code
if isPresentingInAddActionMode {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController{
    owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If I understood your question and intent correctly then it doesn't matter for you who (which class) presented your detailVC and you care only about how your detailVC was presented - either pushed in navigation view controller or presented modally. I think just by checking `presentingViewController` property you can get that information.

Comment: I did check which is the presenter; it is a viewcontroller but not of type UINavigationController, nor the type or instance of my view controller with a tableview. The one ancestor which is presented modally is the embedding UINavigationController. So no luck there. Also the boolean check is reported as invalid instead of false. You are right that  my only care is how the VC is presented so it can be dismissed or popped of the stack the right way.

Comment: @KvdLingen what do you mean by invalid boolean check? Could you please elaborate (or maybe post logs or screenshot)?

Comment: Ended up putting my own variable in the viewController. And set it in the prepareForSegue method of the presenting viewController. This works fine. Thanks for your suggestions.